# How to load a script in a template footer - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter, templating

I'm trying out a more maintainable way to structure my code as learnt by some tutorials at nettuts+.

I've succeeded in making my header and footer files separate from the main content of each page so that they are loaded along with each different page, thus making it easier to manage changes to these two files.

I currently want to add some jQuery code to my footer, for only one page. This is where I've hit a wall in thinking. How can I allow this jQuery code to be present in my footer for only one page, and not all pages? Could someone please explain?

I was thinking of doing something like:

```
<?php if($title = "The jQuery Page"){?>
    <script>
       jquery code here....
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

But I think that is considered messy, as you are using one language to set off another.

Edit: Here's the requested code:

In my Controller I call the views:

```
 $data['title'] = "The jQuery Page";
    $this->load->view('header', $data);
    $this->load->view('cool_page');
    $this->load->view('footer');
```

Then in my footer I want to load a specific script in only this one pages footer:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                /*cool jquery stuff*/

            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Can you add the code for controller(s), template(s), etc.?

Comment: @quantme Sure, just did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to load a `view` into the main `view`

### /application/controllers/test.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Test extends CI_Controller {
  public function index() {
    $data = array(
      'title' => "The jQuery Page", 
      'script' => TRUE // if you omit or comment this variable the 'views/script.php' is not loaded
    );
    $this->load->view('test', $data);
  }
}
```

### /application/views/test.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $title;?></title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php if (isset($script)) { $this->load->view('script'); } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

### /application/views/script.php

```
<script>
  jquery code here....
</script>
```

Comment: Wow that is a really good solution. I wouldn't even need the if condition in the test.php view, because I can just call the script view whenever I need it from the controller! It's like have a sub-footer inside a footer. Great solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could specify JS to include as part of the data passed to the view:

**CONTROLLER1**

```
$this->data['js'][] = 'alert(\'Hi\');';
$this->data['js'][] = 'alert(\'Hey\');';

$this->load->view('footer', $this->data);
```

**CONTROLLER2**

```
$this->data['js'][] = 'alert(\'Yo\');';
$this->data['js'][] = 'alert(\'Sup\');';

$this->load->view('footer', $this->data);
```

**Footer VIEW**

```
if(isset($js) && is_array($js) && count($js) > 0){
    echo '<script>';
    foreach($js as $key=>$value){
        $value;
    }
    echo '</script>';
}
```

Comment: Hi, Is this the same as checking in the view to see if any JavaScript should be executed? If I checked to see if the title was the same and make a conditional statement in the footer view to see if the title is the right page, could that also work

Comment: @a7omiton Yes that could work but you are setting yourself up for a big headache later. This would also break the guidelines of good MVC design which is to essentially separate logic from presentation. If your website project is so small that it is convenient for you to implement your idea then in all honesty you probably do not need the overhead of implementing a framework such as CodeIgniter

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it is a small project but I was thinking of using CodeIgniter to add security (because well, who doesn't need security?) and to give a good foundation for the future in case the website needs to be expanded.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way around making a conditional 'if' statement around the script, so I used the suggested solution in my question.

Check the title to see if it is the desired page:

```
<?php if($title = "Photo Albums - Hands of Humanity"):?>
```

Then add the script to the DOM if it is so:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

//jquery stuff

});
</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

If there are other ways which are better for maintainability, I would be happy to hear them